# How to calculate time spent in Facebook application?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to trace each user time spent in my Facebook application.

I really don't have any idea how to code this, help me out. If someone has any ideas or hints, that will be enough.

I am using Graph API.

Answer (score 1):

**Either: Google Analytics**

The easiest solution of course is using Google Analytics - FBML (Facebook Markup Language) 
has a tag specifically for that: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/google-analytics

That of course doesn't give you data on what a specific user did, but it is pretty good at telling you the time spent on various pages in your Facebook app. And morally its much nicer not to store what a specific user did exactly on your site.

**Or: Self-coded solution**

If you *do* want to track everything specifically, you'll first need to store when a page was accessed using PHP when loading the site and then storing in 10-seconds-intervals (or so) that the user is still present, using an AJAX call. To do that, I'd give the page view an ID and send a request to a page like this *i_am_still_here.php?p={page_view_id}* which takes the current timestamp and updates a database entry for that page view.

This solution has one problem: When a user opens a tab in the background and doesn't look at it for 30 minutes, you don't really want to store that 30 minutes as "the user being on the site".
Also, make sure that with whatever self-coded solution you choose, you have to take into consideration that people might have your Facebook app opened in more than one tab.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not Facebook related per se. There are many ways you could implement this, it also depends on your particular application.

You could track every click a user makes (timestamp of the click) and then calculate the time spent from that (last click in session - first click in session). This approach is not very accurate off course since you don't know how many time a user was still using your application after the last click.

One other solution that comes to mind right now, would be to fire a XHR (AJAX) request every X seconds that would also log the timestamp in some storage (db, redis, memcache, ...) and you could then do the same calculation from that. It would be more accurate (depending on your interval X).

Comment: Do Facebook [Insights](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/) gives a user specific logs?

Comment: thanQ...any new diea plz share

Answer (score -1):

You can easily calculate the time spent on Facebook by downloading a software called [TimRabbit](http://www.gigawatch.com/TimeRabbit/#) which is a desktop application and starts automatically calculates your time spent on facebook. It only calculates your live time spent and ignores when you are acting as a idle user.
For details visit: http://etechdiary.com/calculate-time-spent-on-facebook/